# Binary and continuous variable conversion for neural network analyses

Tags: neural-networks, binary-data, continuous-data

I am a little confused about how to handle binary variables and continuous variables before being fed into a neural network in R. Please can you confirm that I should normalize all variables to fall between 0 and 1 to ensure each variable has the same input weight?

For example I have one variable which is color and I have converted this to binary (i.e. Blue=1 or 0, yellow = 1 or 0 and so on), I also have another variable that has sizes in mm ranging from 7 mm - 1500 mm. What would be the best way to normalize all this data so that it is all on the same sort of scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalizing your input is generally a good idea in order to achieve a well-defined problem. If you don't normalize, your training might be very slow or might end up in a local minimum. The intuitive explanation is that if you have a variable with very large variables, the change in weights from back-propagation will be very different than for any other (smaller) variables.

The variables don't necessarily need to fall between 0 and 1, in fact it is generally recommended to normalize with a mean of 1 and a standard deviation of 1. Your approach should also work however.

The above is only about simple normalization/rescaling. If you have very noisy or assymetrical data, you might also consider transformation to make your input more smooth. See also [this](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_trans). In theory the neural network should be able to handle most of the alinearity in your data though, provided you use non-linear activation functions.